# Editing pure JavaScript extensions directly in Chromium

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, workflow

I'm developing a JavaScript extension for Chromium and my current workflow is:

1. Edit file
2. Uninstall old file
3. Install new file
4. Test file

Is there a quicker way of doing this?

I'm using `chromium-browser_5.0.375.125` in **Ubuntu 10.04**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Load your extension into Chromium
2. Find your extension's ID:

   1. Go to the extensions page `chrome://extensions/`
   2. Click `+ Developer Mode`
   3. Scroll down to your extension and look at the `ID:` field
3. Open `~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/ID/VERSION/script.js` in a text editor
4. Now simply edit, save, and test

For a pure JavaScript extension the version number should be `1.0`.